# Matrix pencil of quadratic form $F + \lambda B$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

Consider a matrix pencil of quadratic form $F + \lambda B$ with $F, B$ are symmetric and positive definite.

For which $\lambda$ is $F + \lambda B \geq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

If "greater or equal to $0$" means positive semidefinite, this is true for $\lambda \ge -\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.